# como obtener los valores de un componente TextInput en react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Genere dinamicamente unos componentes de TextInput en ReactNative pero no puedo obtener los valores que el usuario captura, creo que lo mejor seria agregarlos a un array o directamente al state pero no logro hacerlo, intente de varias maneras que me encontre en foros pero sin resultado

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //this.changeLoading = this.changeLoading.bind(this)
    super(props);
    this.enviar = this.enviar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      arr: {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        value: ""
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    var arreglos2 = [];
    data = this.props.carga.slice();
    return (
      <View style={styles.form_Container}>
        {data.map((objeto, i) => (
          <View key={"n" + i} style={styles.dateD_Info}>
                <View key={"x" + i}>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.textbox3}
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"
                    placeholder=""
                    editable={true}
                    maxLength={5}
                    placeholderTextColor="#0891eb"
                    onChangeText={value => console.log(arreglos2.push({id:i,cantidad:value}))}
                    value={arreglos2[i]}
                  />
                </View>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

los elementos no se guardan y despues no puedo recuperarlos para incrustarlos en un objeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo guardas en el state de esta forma

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //this.changeLoading = this.changeLoading.bind(this)
    super(props);
    this.enviar = this.enviar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        textInput: [],
      };
    };
  }

  render() {
    data = this.props.carga.slice();
    const { textInput } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.form_Container}>
        {data.map((objeto, i) => (
          <View key={"n" + i} style={styles.dateD_Info}>
                <View key={"x" + i}>
                  <TextInput
                    style={styles.textbox3}
                    keyboardType="phone-pad"
                    placeholder=""
                    editable={true}
                    maxLength={5}
                    placeholderTextColor="#0891eb"
                    onChangeText={value =>
                      const newTextInputState = textInput;
                      newTextInputState[i] = value;
                      this.setState({textInput: newTextInputState});
                    }
                    value={textInput[i]}
                  />
                </View>
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: le cambie el textInput por this.state.textInput al codigo que me pasaste y funciono genial

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado!